# ignore key-prefix while routing in S3 routing policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there a way I could ignore a key prefix? or redirect to a url without changing the url in the address bar?

For instance, I have the following url `x.com/y/uuid/` I want s3 to route me to `x.com/y/index.html` without removing/replacing the `/uuid/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> redirect to a url without changing the url in the address bar

Then it wouldn't be a redirect.  An HTTP redirect, by definition, sends the browser to a new location, and the address bar gets rewritten.

Some web server software has a concept of internally rewriting a URL for subsequent processing so that the target resolves to a different path than it otherwise might, but S3 does not support this -- except for the case of automatic index documents, where `example.com/foo` will trigger a browser redirect to `example.com/foo/` which will then internally be rewritten by S3 to return the object with the key `foo/index.html` if it exists. (The browser redirect keeps relative paths sane; without it, a relative path in `/foo/index.html` would be incorrectly interpreted as relative to the root, instead of relative to `/foo/` -- all correctly-behaving web servers do this when rendering index documents.)

S3 custom error documents are also essentially an internal rewrite, of course.

But what you contemplate is not supported by S3.

CloudFront in front of S3 can even do the exact opposite of what you're looking for, so that, for example, `example.com/bar.html` could be presented to the back-end as a request for `example.com/foo/bar.html` without a browser redirect (by configuring a custom origin and setting the Origin Path to `/foo`) but neither service supports removing/hiding/masking path parts without a browser redirect.